# getslice deprecated in Python2.6, but still in use when subclassing tuple?

Tags: python, python-2.6, slice

Consider the following example, executed under Python 2.6.6 (which I'm unfortunately stuck with at the moment):

```
>>> class A:
...     def __getitem__(self, index):
...             print(type(index))
...     def __getslice__(self, start, end):
...             print("Don't call me, I'm deprecated")
...
>>> a = A()
>>> a[3]
<type 'int'>
>>> a[3:3]
<type 'slice'>
```

As it should be, the slicing also call `__getitem__`.
Now alter the definition to subclassing `tuple`:

```
>>> class B(tuple):
...     def __getitem__(self, index):
...             print(type(index))
...     def __getslice__(self, start, end):
...             print("Don't call me, I'm deprecated")
...
>>> b = B()
>>> b[3]
<type 'int'>
>>> b[3:]
Don't call me, I'm deprecated
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Worth considering: http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/39143-rationale-behind-deprecation-__getslice__  Additionally, see: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#additional-methods-for-emulation-of-sequence-types for an authoritative explanation in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to historical reasons, `__getslice__` in some places still gets used for builtin types. So for a tuple, it does get used for the `[i:j]` style syntax of slicing. See: http://bugs.python.org/issue2041 for a brief description and the highlighted caveats in [the **getslice** documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#additional-methods-for-emulation-of-sequence-types)